# Replacing selective numbers with NaNs

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, nan

I have eight columns of data. Colulmns 1,3, 5 and 7 contain 3-digit numbers. Columns 2,4,6 and 8 contain 1s and zeros and correspond to 1, 3, 5 and 7 respectively. Where there is a zero in an even column I want to change the corresponding number to NaN.  More simply, if it were

```
155            1           345           0
328            1           288           1
884            0           145           0
326            1           332           1
159            0           186           1
```

then 884 would be replaced with NaN, as would 159, 345 and 145 with the other numbers remaining the same.  I need to use NaN to maintain the data in matrix form.
I know I could use

```
data(3,1)=Nan; data(5,1)=Nan
```

etc but this is very time consuming.  Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would split the problem into two matrices, with one being a logical mask, the other holding your data.

```
data = your_mat(:,1:2:end);
valid = your_mat(:,2:2:end);
```

Then you can simply do:

```
data(~valid)=NaN;
```

You could then rebuild your data by doing:

```
your_mat(:,1:2:end) = data;
```

Answer (score 4):

**Approach 1**

```
a1 = [
    155            1           345           0
    328            1           288           1
    884            0           145           0
    326            1           332           1
    159            0           186           1]

t1 = a1(:,[2:2:end])
data1 = a1(:,[1:2:end])

t1(t1==0)=NaN
t1(t1==1)=data1(t1==1)

a1(:,[1:2:end]) = t1
```

Output -

```
a1 =

   155     1   NaN     0
   328     1   288     1
   NaN     0   NaN     0
   326     1   332     1
   NaN     0   186     1
```

**Approach 2**

```
[x1,y1] = find(~a1(:,[2:2:end]))
a1(sub2ind(size(a1),x1,2*y1-1)) = NaN
```

Comment: +1 for approach 2, but it seems that the answer by Raab70 would dominate approach 1.

Comment: Thanks, I agree mine is a bit simpler but approach 2 is really interesting.

Comment: Agreed on that @DennisJaheruddin!

Comment: Approach 1 is what I need. In fact, @Raab70 answer slightly simpler for me.   Although not mentioned in question, I will only need the t1 data so Approach 2 not quite what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting solution, I would expect it to perform quite well, but be aware that it is a bit tricky!

```
data(~data(:,2:end))=NaN
```

Comment: Interesting solution ... but fails if you have a 0 in any odd column: you'll write nan in the masking columns.

Comment: @Bentoy13 As mentioned, it is a bit tricky. However as the question mentions 3 digit numbers this should be ok.

Comment: Oops, you're totally right! I forgot this restriction, so I was searching way too far ... congrats!

Comment: Brilliant one-line! Hadn't mentioned in question that actually only need the columns of data with the NaNs, not the reference columns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution. You can use `circshift`, in the following manner.

First create a mask of the even columns of the same size of your input matrix A:

```
AM = false(size(A)); AM(:,2:2:end) = true;
```

Then circshift the mask `(A==0)&AM` one element to the left, to shift this mask on the odd columns.

```
A(circshift((A==0)&AM,[0 -1])) = nan;
```

NOTE: I've searched for a one-liner ... I don't think it's a good one, but here is one you can use, based on my solution:

```
A(circshift(bsxfun(@and, A==0, mod(0:size(A,2)-1,2)),[0 -1])) = nan;
```

The dirty thing with `bsxfun` is to create on-line the mask AM. I use for that the oddness test on a vector of indices, `bsxfun` extends it over the whole matrix A. You can do anything else to create this mask, of course.

Comment: It seems to work, but I am not sure whether I understand your last comment. A circshift approach would always require a full mask right?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Indeed I was not very clear. I just want to emphasize that the method for generating the mask (taking the modulo of the index vector) is not unique, you can do what you want here. But yes, you have to build a full mask.

Comment: This works but, although not in original question, I need a final matrix with only the columns with the NaNs, not the reference numbers. Tried the one-liner but got error message 'undefined function or variable 'a'. But I may be doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3560490 I correct the one-liner, this must be a 'A' instead of 'a'. If you want only the matrix with the numbers, this is much more simpler, and other answers will be fine for that, sorry to have misunderstood it :)

Comment: This is great. I think I understand how circshift works but don't get bsxfun so will just accept the whole line as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Using logical indexing:

```
even = a1(:,2:2:end);    % even columns
odd  = a1(:,1:2:end);    % odd columns
odd(even == 0) = NaN;    % set odd columns to NaN if corresponding col is 0
a1(:,1:2:end)  = odd;    % assign back to a1

a1 = 
   155     1   NaN     0
   328     1   288     1
   NaN     0   NaN     0
   326     1   332     1
   NaN     0   186     1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is good to see that you want to contribute but make sure that besides reading the question, you also check the existing answers. In this case the existing answer of @Raab70 is practically identical so posting it would typically not be encouraged. Just look around and I am sure you will find enough questions where you can help the asker!

Comment: My bad, I noticed this after I posted.

Comment: Actually, I am very new to writing code so setting it out so clearly, with comments, is extremely helpful. Thanks.